# Maven dependency for org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.contrib.HSSFRegionUtil

Tags: maven, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I am converting an existing ant build project to maven. The project uses the POI-2.5-FINAL and JXL jar files for writing data to excel. Although I have added the POI jar in the pom.XML dependencies, running maven build is failing due to the following compilation error : 
error: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.contrib does not exist!
Note that all other classes from org.Apache.poi.hssf.usermodel such as HSSFWorkbook, HSSFSheet are not giving any error.
Also the code runs successfully in ant build.
Please let me know how I can solve this error.
Thanks.

Comment: Switch to latest version, 2.5 is ancient.

Comment: but it worked with the ant build..

Comment: coz you may have all the jars while building with Ant but not with Maven

Comment: Apache POI 2.5 is over 10 years old! Why not upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to 2.5, try adding below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-contrib-2.5-final</artifactId>
    <version>20040302</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Garry. but adding the above dependency is giving me the following compile time error : The type org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files

Comment: Tried using poi-3.5.. Same Error as poi 2.5

Comment: @Shruti21 .. atleast you progressed, class not found/resolved can be resolved by googling. Try to search for dependency for the missing class and add it to your pom. Indirectly referenced class files are required by dependencies you added.